# How to reset the table values in AX 2012?

Tags: record, axapta

Can I use like this to reset the table variable in AX?

I have tried with the below piece of code:

```
Table_Name.RecId=0;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the .clear() method that is available on all tables to clear/reset all table fields, including the RecId field.

```
Table_Name.clear();
```

Comment: In my case I had to assign the table to null per @mazzy's answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered deleting the record instead?

```
Table_Name.delete();
```

The field `RecId` identifies the record and cannot meaningful be reset.

Comment: see `OverwriteSystemFields` method on a table variable :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear is to erase field values of te object in order to rehuse the object in a loop. Delete has a direct impact into SQL Database.

Answer (score 1):

Full reset for all data fields and behaviour features:

```
TableName = null;
```

see feature [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603129/how-to-check-that-next-operator-can-be-used). `TableName.clear();` clears only data fields.

Comment: You saved me a lot of headache, thanks for adding this here!