# How to check that next operator can be used?

Tags: axapta

Questions for any Axapta version:

1. How to check that 'next' operator can be used with record?
2. How to suppress a debugger on unacceptable 'next' operator?

Thanks.

---

Code for reproduce:

```
static void Job13(Args _args)
{
    CustTrans   ct1;
    CustTrans   ct2;

    // let's assume that method 'one' search a record
    select ct1; // where ct1.AccountNum == 'someAccount'
    ct2.data(ct1.data());

    // contract postcondition
    Debug::assert(ct1.RecId != 0);
    Debug::assert(ct2.RecId == ct1.RecId);

    //////////////////////////////////

    // let's assume that method 'two' accepts a custTrans record as parameter
    Debug::assert(ct2.RecId != 0);
    try
    {
        // Questions:
        // 1. How to check that 'next' can be used?
        // 2. How to suppress a debugger?
        next ct2;
    }
    catch
    {
        Warning('catch it!');
    }
}
```

+a couple of screenshots that created after job runs in ax2009.

[image: Debugger]

[image: infolog after debugger]

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but have you considered using `while select` or a collection to pass the records and then iterating over the collection? To ask another way, what's your reason for using `next`?

Comment: I'm agree - `while select` is good solution and `queryRun` is brilliant. Reason is `Enumerator on xRecord`. https://github.com/mazzy-ax/SysEnumerators/blob/master/ax2009/Src/SysEnumerators/Class_SysEnumerator_Record.xpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa845764.aspx):

> The select statement only fetches one record, or field. To fetch
>   additional records, you can use the next statement. The next statement
>   fetches the next record in the table. **If you use next without a
>   preceding select command, an error occurs.** Do not use next with the
>   firstOnly find option. If you need to traverse a number of records, it
>   is more appropriate to use a while select statement.

You have used **next** command with *ct2* without preceding **select** command (which you used with *ct1*).

**Update:** Using `if (ct1.found()) next ct1;` can help you avoid unexpected errors.

Comment: Thanks ). Question is: How to check that 'next' operator can be used with record?

Comment: I've updated my answer with suggestion to use `if (ct2.found()) next ct2;`

Comment: The method found() defined for ax2012 only. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `ct2.data(ct1.data());` and it is the `(d)` part of your error message. It looks like AX just can't handle that scenario. I agree with @FH-Inway's comment, that you should probably use `while select ct1 {}` instead of using `next`.

The below demonstrates it more clearly:

```
static void Job5(Args _args)
{
    SalesTable      salesTable;
    SalesTable      salesTable2;

    select salesTable where salesTable.SalesId == 'SO-001351';

    while (salesTable)
    {
        info(salesTable.SalesId);

        next salesTable;
    }

    info("Above has no issue");

    select salesTable where salesTable.SalesId == 'SO-001351';
    salesTable2.data(salesTable);

    while (salesTable2)
    {
        info(salesTable2.SalesId);

        next salesTable2;
    }

    info("Above fails");
}
```

Comment: thanks. `ct2.data(ct1.data())`, `ct2.data(ct1)`, `buf2buf()` does not work. I'm argee - It looks like AX just can't handle that scenario.